# Website url escaping using regex

Tags: php, regex

My code is

```
<?php
$crunch = "http://thecruncworld.com";
$something = preg_match'/('/^(([\w]+:)?\/\/)?(((([\d\w]|%[a-xA-x\d]{2,2})/'
echo $something;
?>
```

Here i just need to escape my website url with regex .When i execute this code i am getting an error like this ..

```
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''/('' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\yeah.php on line 3
```

Is it possbile on regex ..If its possible please tell me how ..

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean 'escape' the url?

Comment: I need the output as ..Match URL: http://thecrunchworld.com

Comment: Your `preg_match` function call is not even complete, what are you expecting from your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use an already set up function, such as `urlencode()` to escape data for inclusion in a URL. For more info, see this page: https://www.php.net/urlencode

Comment: is regex important in programming .i think its not so imp ?

Comment: Well yes, regex is very useful; however, it can also quickly become complicated and difficult to debug. As such, when possible, it's best to use reliable built-in functions.

Comment: Also, if this solved your problem, please accept this answer so others are aware of the solution.